# can not figure out relation between yaml and main page handler in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, yaml

I've have search a lot in google and stackoverflow but can't figure out qhy my code is not working,

app.yaml file follows:

```
application: morgan629200774
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:

- url: /.*
  script: main.app

- url: /unit1/
  script: unit1.app

- url: /unit2/
  script: unit2.app

- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico


libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```

and here is my code:

```
import webapp2






form = """
<form method="post">
    Enter some text to ROT13
    <br>
    <br>
    <div><textarea name="content" rows="7" cols="50"></textarea></div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
    <br>
    <br>
</form>
"""

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
     def get(self):
        self.response.out.write("main page")   

class unit1(webapp2.RequestHandler):
     def get(self):
        self.response.out.write("hello world")

class unit2(webapp2.RequestHandler):
     def get(self):
        self.response.out.write(form)
        self.response.out.write("hello world")
     def post(self):
        rot13=''  
        text=self.request.get('content')
        rot13=text.encode('rot13')
        self.response.out.write(rot13)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/.*', MainPage),
    ('/unit1/', unit1),
    ('/unit2/', unit2)
], debug=True)
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You haven't got (and don't need) a `unit1.app` or `unit2.app`, so I don't know why you've referenced them in app.yaml. As you can see from the Python code, there is one object called `app`, which contains the routes for the whole application. I presume (although you don't state) that the Python file is called "main.py". which is why the app.yaml refers to `main.app` - ie the `app` object in the `main` module.

The purpose of the URLs in app.yaml is simply to hand off to the Python code. So, you only need a single handler: the first one. Delete the other two handlers. That captures *everything* under `/` and passes it to main.app. In that file, the first route defined at the bottom should be:

```
('/', MainPage)
```

because you don't want to capture everything in that route, only the specific root URL.

Comment: Thanks! OK I deletd app1 and app2 from the yaml file but now I get a 404 error when I try to run the code in localhost:port/unit1 or localhost:port/unit2